# Any way to work around the fact that __DATA__ is not a filehandle, even though it's referred that way in all the documentation

Tags: perl, filehandle

All the documentation I've been reading about `__DATA__` says stuff like, "the special filehandle" but it's not a filehandle is it?

https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Special-Literals

> The DATA file handle by default has whatever PerlIO layers were in place when Perl read the file to parse the source."

```
#!/bin/env perl                                                                                                                                                                                   

open($config, "<test.pl");

$config_copy = $config; # let's me copy a filehandle

while (<$config_copy>) {
  print $_;  # works just fine
}

$config_copy = __DATA__;  # FAIL syntax error does not let me copy a filehandle

while (<$config_copy>) {
  print $_;
}

__DATA__                                                                                                                                                                                          
1                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2                                                                                                                                                                                                 
3                                                                                                                                                                                                 
4                                                                                                                                                                                                 
5
```

I basically want to hand a filehandle to a config file reader function OR pass in `__DATA__` if it exists,  but the reader function is in a different package than the `__DATA__` segment, so I need to pass `__DATA__` as a parameter because `__DATA__` is only accessible from the same package or file it's declared in but perl is not treating `__DATA__` like other file handles. It can't be assigned or passed as a function argument.

```
------ package ConfigReader ------------------
package ConfigReader;

sub ReadConfig {
   my ($handle) = @);
   while($handle) {
       # blah blash
   }
}

----------- application ------------------

use ConfigReader;
    
# it won't let me set a scalar to __DATA__.
# but it lets scalars be set to other file handles.

my $config_handle = __DATA__ # set up default, FAIL syntax error
open($config_handle, "<$config_file_name")

my $configs = ConfigReader::ReadConfig($config_handle);

--------------------------
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `\*DATA` ?

Answer (score 6):

As you quote from the documentation:

> The `DATA` file handle by default has whatever PerlIO layers were in place when Perl read the file to parse the source.

It also says this:

> Text after __DATA__ may be read via the filehandle `PACKNAME::DATA`, where `PACKNAME` is the package that was current when the __DATA__ token was encountered.

The filehandle is called **DATA**, not **__DATA__**. In some cases, you might need to refer to it by taking a reference to the glob that contains it - `\*DATA` - but those occasions seem to be rare these days.

So try:

```
$config_copy = DATA;
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. My intuition was telling me that any "internal" data, including a special file handle, would retain the underscores __DATA__ to avoid collision with user symbols. But that only goes so far. (stack overflow swallows underscores)

Comment: Re "*but those occasions seem to be rare these days.*", Well, any time you want to pass it to a sub

Comment: DATA sets itself aside from other symbols by being in all caps. Several other special symbols in Perl do that too.